# JQuery Ajax submitHandler() after validate a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I use the JQuery library and I try to pass ajax when my form is validated with `submitHandler`.

I'm looking to check if the account information is correct. However I make a problem, in my condition of the success function in Ajax, I would like the form to load if data is not equal to zero. So my condition works well if I put a bad password, it detects zero. However if I put the correct password, my form loads and redirects me to my home page and not to the user profile page. PHP sessions are not even created elsewhere, as if it were ignored.

Jquery :

```
submitHandler: function (form) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "App/Actions/PlayerCheckAuthentication.php",
        data: $("form[name='auth']").serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            if (data == 0) {
                console.log(data)
                $(".input-container").eq(5).append("<label class='box gray b_error'>Password incorrect.</label>");
                $(":input[name='password']").addClass("red");
            } else {
                form.submit();
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
},
```

PHP Ajax Call :

```php
<?php

require '../../vendor/autoload.php';

use App\Models\AuthManager as Auth;
use App\Config;

$Auth = new Auth();

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if (isset($username) && isset($password)) {
    if ($Auth->auth($username, $password)) {
        echo "true";
        header("Location: " . Config::APP_URL . "/me");
    } else {
        echo "false";
    }
}
```

PHP Function

```
    public function auth($username, $password)
    {
        $array = Model::getDB()->get("users", "*", ["username" => $username]);
        $count = Model::getDB()->count("users", ["username" => $username]);

        if ($count > 0) {
            if (password_verify($password, $array['password'])) {
                $_SESSION['user'] = array();

                foreach ($array as $user => $key) {
                    //unset($_SESSION['user']['password']);
                    $_SESSION['user'][$user] = $key;
                }
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Redirect on the client-side if XHR responses with `"true"`.

Comment: How to do it in jquery?

Comment: remove this `header("Location: " . Config::APP_URL . "/me");` and just  `echo true`

Comment: I just removed it but it doesn't work

Comment: Ok so I use the jquery `.done()` function to display an XHR response. However it reloads my index page and it does not redirect to the profile, still no session is created.

Comment: It's somehow odd, that you're echoing "true/false" from PHP, but checking `0` in the success handler. As Muhammad stated, remove the header from PHP, and then in the success handler check if `data` is "true", and if it is, do `window.location.href = "newUrl"`. You've to know the value of `Config::APP_URL` at the client to create the url, though.

Comment: I know the value of `Config::APP_URL`, I know exactly where it should redirect but as said I have the impression that my function in PHP does not work. Normally it creates a "user" session if the password matches the username but in ajax it doesn't seem to work

Comment: show your code where it validates user `email` and `password` to sign in a user @BenjaminPeuple

Comment: I edited my post and added the function

Comment: in your else replace `form.submit()` with `window.location.href = "<?php Config::APP_URL; ?>" your success URL and check`

Comment: It doesn't work, I just tried...

Comment: Dump your session value and check there is any user's session or not @BenjaminPeuple

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210853/discussion-between-muhammad-shareyar-and-benjamin-peuple).

Comment: `array(1) { ["error"]=> array(0) { } }` No existing user session, I really don't understand, as if my form didn't send anything.

Comment: @MuhammadShareyar have just fixed my problem. I forgot to start my session with session_start() in PHP simply